# PdoException when Updating composer, could not find driver

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to update php composer, but am receiving the error below:

I attempted to fix it by installing pd_mysql, but that didn't work:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd php5-mysql
```

How can I update my composer?

```
jon@debian:~/NetBeansProjects/xxx$ php composer.phar update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Generating autoload files
> Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters
Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache


  [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]              
  An exception occured in driver: could not find driver  



  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]  
  could not find driver                



  [PDOException]         
  could not find driver  


Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception


  [RuntimeException]                                                         
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:  

    [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]                                
    An exception occured in driver: could not find driver                    


    [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]                                      
    could not find driver                                                    


    [PDOException]                                                           
    could not find driver                                                    

  .                                                                          


update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Comment: what's the output of `php -m`?

Comment: [PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dba
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache

Comment: I have managed to get it to work with php5. However, in php7, pdo_mysql doesn't seem to be in the modules list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution.

My php version was 7.0, which was installed using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php-7.0
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0
```

(source https://www.colinodell.com/blog/2015-12/installing-php-7-0-0)

I then ran

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql
```

Following that, the update worked.